# C# windows form textbox text select from mouse (to copy, etc...)

Tags: user-interface, c#-4.0, textbox

I am using C# on Visual studio 2012. I have windows form having textbox. I often need to copy text from textbox field. When i tried to select from mouse it doesn't work, as a workaround i need to use ctrl + a from that particular textbox field.
Could you please help me how can i enable it through mouse?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question... This should actually be a basic Windows function unless you have the textbox disabled either through code or from the properties list.

[image]

If by chance you are disabling it in your code you will need to change that by either deleting the code or setting the textbox enable to true.

Using an example from a WinForm that I am using I can right click and use all the basic Windows text functions.

[image]

Furthermore, you should be able to do this as well... Using the Mouse Click event for the text box you can automate the whole thing by just clicking on the text inside the text box.

```
private void textBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.SelectAll();
        textBox1.Copy();
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I made changes in properties of textbox like you mentioned above that wasn't worked :( However with MouseClick  event it allows to select whole text at once but doesn't show up on right click copy like you have shown above.

Comment: You can physically select the text in the text field correct? 
if you use the code textBox1.SelectAll(); and textBox1.Copy(); it will automatically copy the text to your Windows clipboard.  Then all you will need to do is paste it wherever you need to paste it.

Comment: Yes, i can physically select text in the textbox. It looks SelecAll() works but for copy i need to use my keyboard; can't do with mouse. Just a side info, i am using .Net 4 framework and MVS 2012.

Comment: Using the .Net 4.0 framework, the copy method should still work... you just won't get a pop-up menu... it will copy the text automatically without you having to select "copy" from a list of pop-up menu items.

Comment: I have around 10 texbox fields, do i individually create MouseClick event for each field. Isn't it possible to group them all textbox fields together and apply MouseClick event all them at once?

Comment: The only other way that I can think of is by looping through each textbox.
foreach(TextBox t in this.Controls) or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

could you try this

```
  private void textBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)

    {
        textBox2.Text = textBox1.SelectedText;
    }
```